# Why is shellcode usually in Hex format?

Tags: shellcode

Sorry I am new to C programming and shellcodes.

1. Why is a shellcode always in Hex format?
   (e.g. "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x89\xe3\x50\x89\xe2\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80";

Answer (score 4):

Because that's what a shellcode is: a small series of bytes that represent executable machine-language code. For convenience, we choose to represent those bytes in hex notation. And a string of hex characters is a very convenient way of representing a really small, executable piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

First, recall what [shellcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode) is:

> In hacking, a shellcode is a small piece of code used as the payload in the exploitation of a software vulnerability.

We pass this shellcode to a vulnerable bit of software through an exploit, like a buffer overflow attack. And this shellcode is read by the computer during [*runtime*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_time_(program_lifecycle_phase)). At this [stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_lifecycle_phase), the vulnerable software is past the compilation, assembly and linking phases. During runtime, the CPU is purely following instructions and only understands [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_lifecycle_phase) instructions--not assembly, and certainly not higher-level programming languages.

The hexadecimal format in which you've written your shellcode, is machine code that the CPU understands.

This [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/220766) gives a similar answer.